# Update cell only if NULL (or if cell has value 'Unoccupied')?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to update a value in an SQLite3 database. The database has two columns: Seat_Number and Name. There are 30 records altogether in this table. The Seat_Number column holds integers 1 to 30 respectively and all values in the Name column have been written as 'Unoccupied'.

I was wondering if there was a way to UPDATE a cell in the Name column if the user enters a seat number between 0 and 30, but only if the value in the Name column is 'Unoccupied'. Also, if there is a way to do this, would it be easier to set all values in the Name column to NULL?

Here's what I have so far:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('league.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def book_tickets():
    option_1 = True
    name = raw_input("Enter name: ")

    if len(name)>0:
        validated = False
        seat_no = 0
        while validated == False:
            sn = raw_input("Enter seat number: ")

            try:
                seat_no = int(sn)
                validated = True
            except:
                print "Invalid seat number"

            if seat_no >= 1 and seat_no <= 30 and validated == True:
                c.execute("UPDATE Seats SET Name = ? WHERE Seat_Number = ? AND Name = 'Unoccupied'",(name,seat_no))
                conn.commit()

                while option_1:
                    option_1 = raw_input("\t \t Book another seat? \t")

                    if option_1 == "Y" or option_1 == "y" or option_1 == "YES" or option_1 == "yes":
                        book_tickets()

                    elif option_1 == "N" or option_1 == "n" or option_1 == "NO" or option_1 == "no":
                        book_tickets()

                    elif option_1 == "":
                        print "Goodbye!"

                    else:
                        print gap
                        print "Invalid option"

            elif seat_no < 1 or seat_no > 30:
                print "Invalid seat number"
                book_tickets()

            else:
                print "Invalid input."
                book_tickets()

    else:
        print "You didn't enter your name."
        book_tickets()

book_tickets()
```

The rest of the code is fine and mainly just to get the user to input a number between 0 and 31, but I just want the program to tell the user that if the value in Name isn't 'Unoccupied' where Seat_Number = seat_no, then print 'Seat is already booked' and prompt them to enter another seat number. But if the value in Name is anything other than 'Unoccupied' where Seat_Number = seat_no, then SET Name = name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing the `UPDATE`, check `c.rowcount`.

If it's zero, then no rows were updated, and you can print a "Couldn't book" message.

If it's one, then a row matched the condition and was updated, and you can print a "Booking successful" message.

(If it's more than one, then multiple rows were updated. Assuming that `Seat_Number` is unique, then you have a bug.)